# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: jmeter

I am getting an issue as poolableconnectionfactory. how to do it and where i did the mistake?can anyone please suggest me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a bad question setup. You need to structure your post my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Your `sqldatabase322` user doesn't have permissions to connect to the `sqldatabase233` from the `182.72.70.197` IP address.

1. Connect to your MySQL database server as [root user](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-access-mysql-with-the-mysql-root-user)
2. Execute [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html) and [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) commands like:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'sqldatabase322'@'182.72.70.197' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password_here';
   GRANT ALL PR on sqldatabase233.* to 'sqldatabase322'@'182.72.70.197' with grant option;
   ```
3. Now you should be able to connect to the database and execute arbitrary queries

Check out [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection/) article for comprehensive information/troubleshooting options.